# CSS settings failure

Tags: html, css

I cannot understand how CSS resolves values.

mt_sim.css

```
table.runsim_table {
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;

        border-top-width: 15px;
        border-bottom-width: 15px;
        border-left-width: 15px;
        border-right-width: 15px;
}

tr.runsim_table {
        border-top-width: 15px;
        border-bottom-width: 15px;
}
```

mt_sim.html

```
<table class="runsim_table">
                <tr class="runsim_table">
                        <td>
                                <SELECT name="sel_tag_name" ng-model="runsim.tag_name" ng-options="tag for tag in runsim.tags">
                                </SELECT>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <button ng-click="sel_pulldown ()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Select Tag</button>
                        </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="runsim_table">
                        <td>
                                {{runsim.the_default}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <button ng-click="sel_default ()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Select Default</button>
                        </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="runsim_table">
                        <td>
                                <input type="text" name="sel_tag_typed" ng-model="runsim.tag_name_typed">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <button ng-click="sel_textbox ()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Select Tag</button>
                        </td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

Here is what chrome developer tools computed styles says:

[image: table border width]

Now looking at a table row (tr)

[image: tr border width]

In both cases I am trying to modify the border-xx-width, and in each case it notices my settings but does not use them and shows no other settings that would override it that I can see.

Why is it not using my settings?

If you need more info let me know what you want to see.   I cannot post the entire code as this is a small corner of an angular app.

Comment: did you define anything else for the borders? Like `border:15px solid #000` where it has a style (solid) and a color?

Comment: OK, it looks like you are right.  Without a border color you cannot set the individual border widths.  I changed it to border: solid #000; border-top-width: 5px; and I get what I want but with the black color.   I will research how to get it transparant.

Comment: you want a transparent border? Wouldn't that be what padding is for? or do you mean like rgba(0,0,0,.5) half transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `border-style` is by default set to `none`.
No border is rendered so if you try to change its width value, it won't affect anything.

One solution could be to use a 'border-style: solid;` and then set its color to transparent.

```css
.runsim_table {
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        }

table.runsim_table {
        margin: 5px;
        border-width: 15px;
}

tr.runsim_table {
        border-top-width: 15px;
        border-bottom-width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table class="runsim_table">
                <tr class="runsim_table">
                        <td>
                                <SELECT name="sel_tag_name" ng-model="runsim.tag_name" ng-options="tag for tag in runsim.tags">
                                </SELECT>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <button ng-click="sel_pulldown ()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Select Tag</button>
                        </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="runsim_table">
                        <td>
                                {{runsim.the_default}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <button ng-click="sel_default ()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Select Default</button>
                        </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="runsim_table">
                        <td>
                                <input type="text" name="sel_tag_typed" ng-model="runsim.tag_name_typed">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <button ng-click="sel_textbox ()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Select Tag</button>
                        </td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

or as @Kai Qing noticed, you could use [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) which looks more like what you need.

Comment: This is very clean, CSS has always been a challenge to me but this is clear.  Thanx.